# MySQL Set Based vs Procedural

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables

**accounts**

| id | balance | pending_balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 5 |

**transactions**

| id | account_id | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15 | 2021-03-03 |
| 2 | 1 | 25 | 2021-03-03 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 2021-03-10 |

I have a AFTER INSERT trigger on **transactions** to update **accounts** **balance** and **pending_balance**, and that works well.

The **balance** should only account **transactions** older than 7 days, so I need a second trigger to do it. (it runs EVERY DAY)

I have a query that works:

```
UPDATE
    accounts A
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
            account_id,
            SUM(IF(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= date,value,0)) AS pending,
            SUM(value) AS total
        FROM
            transactions
        GROUP BY
            account_id
    ) AS T ON T.account_id = A.id
SET
    balance = T.total - T.pending,
    pending_balance = T.pending
WHERE
    A.id IN (
        SELECT
            account_id
        FROM
            transactions
        WHERE
            date >= DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
            AND date < DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 DAY))
    )
```

But I'm sure this is not the right way.

**Would a procedural approach perform better?**
**If not, how would one do this properly?**

Comment: This works, ergo it's a question for [codereview.se], not [so]

Comment: it is perfectly ok, much smarter you can 't really make